# Stuck with unit testing largest number in array

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, methods

I am a bit new to C# and unit testing, and we have an assignment in school that I have a hard time understanding, and under the circumstances of corona and school at home, it has been difficult for me to get help from my teacher.

My assignment is to make a method that finds the largest number in an array, and then test it. The array shall also be allowed to be empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Large
{
    public int Find(int[] mynumbers)
    {
        int mylargest = mynumbers[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < mynumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mynumbers[i] > mylargest) mylargest = mynumbers[0];
        }
        return mylargest;
    }
}
```

My teacher made this method but I don't really understand the loop.
I tried to make a test method, but it keeps returning the first integer in my array, as the expected number.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    //arrange
    Large mynumber = new Large();

    //act
    int[] myarray = { 3, 5, 1, 7, 3, 8 };
    int result = mynumber.Find(myarray);

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
}
```

When I try this, my test gets passed. But when I change the result (which should have been the biggest), it fails.

What am I not getting?

To sum up:

- I have to test my method, to see that it indeed finds the largest number
- I have to test my method so it won't throw and exception when the array is empty
- I don't understand it at all, and my teacher can't explain it to me...

Comment: If you walk through the current logic in the `Large` class you will notice that in the loop it is always setting the largest to the first item in the array. => `mylargest = mynumbers[0];`

Comment: That's what confuses me, because my teacher made that code, and according to the assignment, the method is supposed to return the largest number. 
What can I change to do that? Also thank you for the answer.

Comment: I believe the shown code was incorrectly done on purpose for you to try and figure out the logic.

Comment: Your current test proves that the subject code is not correct. Which is part of the exercise, I believe. It is now up to you work fix the method and then test again.

Comment: I tried changing it so that the array had a static value, and then it works, but I still can't figure out, how to allow it to be empty, when it always has a static value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the unit test is to prove the subject code behaves as expected when exercised.

First step is to write a test that asserts the expected behavior.

Based on your current test it should look like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void Large_Find_Should_Return_Largest_Number_In_Array() {
    //arrange
    Large subjectUnderTest = new Large();   //Subject under test
    int[] myarray = { 3, 5, 1, 7, 3, 8 };   //Known input
    int expected = 8;                       //expected output

    //act        
    int actual = subjectUnderTest.Find(myarray); //exercising the subject under test

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);      //verifying/asserting expected behavior
}
```

Running this will fail, proving that the subject under test is not correct.

With the test available to verify the expected behavior, you can now focus attention to fixing the logic of the subject under test.

If you walk through the current logic in the Large class you will notice that in the loop it is always setting the largest to the first item in the array.

```
//...

for (int i = 0; i < mynumbers.Length; i++) {
    if (mynumbers[i] > mylargest) mylargest = mynumbers[0]; <--
}

//..
```

I believe the shown code provided by the teacher was incorrectly done on purpose for you to try and figure out the logic.

Assess the code, try a fix and then confirm behavior using the test and repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got the test and the method to work correctly together. What you wrote was very insightful.
Now I only have to figure out how to allow the array to be empty.

Comment: @Nathalie great. Write the test first of what you would expect. It will fail, obviously, since you have not done the logic yet. But that is the point of having the test first.

Comment: @Nathalie I would also suggest doing some research on Test Driven Development. I believe it would help your understanding of how to write cleaner more manageable code. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: I definitely will, thank you.
I am stuck now, I can't figure out how to allow the array to be empty.

Comment: @Nathalie Did you write the test first?

Comment: Yes, and then I got System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: `// arrange
            Large findlarge = new Large();
            int[] myarray = new int[0];
            int expected = 0;

            // act
            int actual = findlarge.Find(myarray);

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);`

Comment: Perfect. I know the answer, but my hope was to nudge you in the right direction instead of just telling you the answer. I'll ask you some questions that should hopefully guide you along the correct path

Comment: @Nathalie `IndexOutOfRangeException` means that you are asking for an index not in the array. In this case the array is empty. What should you be checking to make sure the array has items?

Comment: That it has a length, is my guess, but not sure how to check that.

Comment: Correct, the `Length`. so you need to check a condition involving the length of the array.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work:
`            if (mynumbers.Length == 0)
            {
                mylargest = 0;
                return mylargest;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mynumbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (mynumbers[i] > mylargest) mylargest = mynumbers[i];
                }
                return mylargest;
            }`

Comment: @Nathalie good attempt. You are headed in the right direction. That can be simplified. `if (mynumbers.Length == 0) return 0;` and leave the rest as it was before

Comment: I actually tried that too, but I still get the same result in the test.

Comment: That shouldn't be. You still get the exception when you pass an empty array?

Comment: Yes, but could it be, that I made an error in the TestMethod? Haven't tried working that much with arrays.

Comment: @Nathalie I tried it using the test you showed in the comments and all tests pass. Look at the example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/HRO01G

Comment: Oh wow, I just had the composition a bit wrong, now everything works. Thank you so much, you've been a star!